# ISO basic script to constantly update a set number adding on more daily

Tags: css, addition

Setting up a new website using CSS3 and I'm toying with a modal. For content, I'd want to put in a number (113) that would have an additional 113 added to the current number daily, resetting at January 1 each year.

For example... it's currently June 13. 18,532 would be the current number displayed, if my sleepy brain is right, and tomorrow it would be 18,654, and the day after, add on another 113, and so on. I'd like something that would do that daily without me updating it, the opposite of a countdown. I do NOT know how to script these things. Does something open source and user-friendly like this exist?